# How does the install process guess the timezone?

Tags: installation, timezone

Is it possible to use the same tool to have Ubuntu guess what timezone it is currently in?

This article mentions the feature I'm looking for (just above the second pic):
http://www.linuxforu.com/2012/05/ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin-review/

Comment: Unfortunately, only one of those questions had an actionable/appropriate answer. I guess 64 is better than 55, but I can select answers just for the sake of improving that.

Comment: Many thanks, Brian. When you have a chance, could you perhaps add comments to those questions/answers as to whats missing, increasing the chances that a good answer will show up in the future?

Comment: Thanks for the tips--as I have time, I'll go through and update them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to download the ubiquity source and dig for it. Greping timezone found the concerned lines, which issue the command:

```
wget -O - -q http://geoip.ubuntu.com/lookup
```

and parse the resulting xml.

Rather than load up python or something else, I just wrote a quick bash script that grabs the xml and yanks the timezone out with sed:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Fetch timezone from Ubuntu's geoip server
TZ=`wget -O - -q http://geoip.ubuntu.com/lookup | sed -n -e 's/.*<TimeZone>\(.*\)<\/TimeZone>.*/\1/p'`

# Set the current time
cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime
```

Comment: Will that work? I thought /etc/localtime was a binary file?  Sure you don't need to do this:

Comment: Yep; the above code works like a charm, and has been in production for a couple years now.

Comment: I'm in Melbourne, Australia, and doing this query from my IP address gives me `CountryCode=AU`, `CountryName=Australia`, `TimeZone=None`. So it deduces the country successfully, but not the timezone within the country.

Answer (score 6):

Ubuntu uses the `ubuntu-geoip` package, which queries http://geoip.ubuntu.com/.

You can `python-geoip` to achieve the same thing:

```
import GeoIP
geo = GeoIP.new(GeoIP.GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE)
ip = '200.100.50.0'
print geo.country_code_by_addr(ip)
```

Sadly, it doesn't work with ipv6 yet.

Comment: I was really hoping that someone might know where that bit of code lives, and if it might be called again....

Comment: I found the exact query to get xml: `wget -O - -q http://geoip.ubuntu.com/lookup`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it uses your internet connection & ip address to find that information. When I have installed offline it always asks you to select a timezone.